# How to fix the error "unsafe:data:image/png;base64, Qk1..." in Angular

Tags: angular, base64

HTML code:

```
<img [src] = "BmdFile_strbase64" class="bmd-img"/>
```

component.ts code:

```
this.BmdFile_strbase64 = "data:image/png;base64, " + this.InfoItem["strBase64_Directory"];
```

I'm getting this error : [image]

```
unsafe:data:image/png;base64, Qk1KXQAAAAAAADoEAAAoAAAAmAAAAJYAAA...
```

I decode from file extension .BMD.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I googled .bmd and got *a bmd 3D Model (Texture + Skeleton) is a special file format by Nintendo* - is this what you got? If so, why do you treat it as png image and want to show it? Whatever it is, it's certainly not a png image.

Comment: also Check https://www.code-sample.com/2017/11/sanitize-value-manually-in-angular.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as  @Shashank Vivek said.
I used sanitizer in Angular
html code:

```
<img [src]="BmdFile_strbase64" class="bmd-img" />
```

component.ts code:

```
BmdFile_strbase64 : SafeResourceUrl;
this.BmdFile_strbase64 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("data:image/bmd;base64, " + this.NcSheetInfoItem["strBase64_Directory"] );
```

And BMD file is showing ok.